c# Windform application,UI becomes white and unable to build(object refernce not set to an instance of an object)
Frequently the UI becomes white and showing object reference not set to an instance of an object
enter image description here
How to resolve this issue.Sometimes the white is visible but the error arises and unable to build the application.What is the major issue in this

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Specifically please post a [mre]. Also see: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.
